# Hierarchical name lookup using regexes

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to parse hierarchical names that are separated by dots like these

> a.b.c.d
>
> a.b.c.c

Now, I have to filter these based on either names or regex patterns (remove them or get them).

So, I tried using a sqlite database with a custom regexp function like this.

```
def regexp(expr, item):
    reg = re.compile(expr)
    if (item in expr):
      return True
    else:
      return (reg.search(item) is not None)
```

And I'm using a query like this

```
for i in list_of_hierarchies: 
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM fault WHERE hierarchy REGEXP  ?", [i])
```

However, this is very slow.  I've a total entry count of around 35000 and the list to be got is around 5000 (can be more or less; regexes or proper names).

How do I make it better?  Am I even using the right tool for the job?

Comment: Depending on the size of the data set, you could opt for retrieving your data into a Pandas DataFrame, and then performing a regexp selection there, either with a function or just plain regexp expression.

Comment: Trouble is, I'm going to use this in a project that will require extra validation on the confidence of the tool being used and I don't think they'll want to evaluate another framework at this point.  Deadlines and all.  (Though I'll take a look at it.

Of course, for pure names, using a set and subtracting is very efficient, but I want regex support as the projects go on, the exceptions to be added will grow in number.

What do you think of using a prefix tree and supporting glob like matches?  That should also be acceptable, I suppose though filtering on regexes would be better.